# Solving partial differential equation using FDM in Matlab

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, matlab

I want to solve the partial differential equation

$$u_{x}(x,y) + f(x)u_{y}(x,y) = f(0)u(0,y),~~x \in (0,A),~ y \in (0,B) $$

$$ u(A,y)=0$$
$$u(x,B)=0 $$
using a finite difference scheme. If I used the explicit finite difference scheme, then I got

$$ u(m+1,n) - u(m,n) + f(m)(u(m,n+1)-u(m,n))=f(1)u(1,n) $$
$$u(M,n)=0; u(m,N)=0 $$ where $m=1,2,...,M$ and $n=1,2,...,N$ and $u(m,n) = u(x(m),y(n))$. But here $u(1,n)$ is unknown and I am getting problem to determine $u(2,n)$. To get rid of this problem,
I used the transformation $x=x_{1}+A,y=y_{1}+B$ to change boundary conditions to $u(0,y_{1}+B)=u(x_{1}+A,0)=0$, but then $f(0)$ is changed into $f(-A)$. This creates problem to write finite difference scheme in Matlab. Please help me to write finite difference scheme to this problem.

Comment: There is no $g$ in the PDE or in the boundary conditions appearing?

Comment: Edited my question.

Comment: Why do you want to do this transformation? You can just solve the problem as it is on this domain.

Comment: If I solve it as it is, then it requires for loop to starts from $i=M,j=N$ instead of $i=1,j=1$ in Matlab.

Comment: Why is this an issue?

Comment: I understand it now, as I was not familiar with inverse loop in Matlab.